# Check parameters of method with 6 input Boolean parameters

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
public boolean my_method(boolean b1, boolean b2, boolean b3, boolean b4, boolean b5, boolean b6){ 
// ... 
}
```

I got asked to write the code so that this method returns true only if two and only two of the parameters list is true.

I'm not sure about the best practice for that. I appreciate your suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest not writing methods with 6 boolean parameters.

Comment: Must the values be provided via single parameters? Could you have like an array being passed in? Then you could just loop through and check if 2 of them are true

Comment: the question came with a method of 6 boolean parameters. It is asked to write the code within this method to return true only if 2 of the parameters is true. It is not me who created this method. is check the parameters one by one the best solution?

Comment: Is the naive solution ever what's wanted in these "clever" interview questions?

Answer (score 4):

I am always a fan of the stream API, so here's one solution:

```
public boolean method(boolean b1, boolean b2, boolean b3, boolean b4, boolean b5, boolean b6) {
    Boolean[] array = { b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6 };
    return Arrays.stream(array).filter(x -> x).count() == 2;
}
```

First, I put all the parameters into an array. Then I filtered all the items that are true and counted them. Finally return whether that count is equal to 2.

Although the above very little code to write, it boxes the `boolean`s into `Boolean`s. If you don't like boxing, try this:

```
public boolean method(boolean b1, boolean b2, boolean b3, boolean b4, boolean b5, boolean b6) {
    boolean[] array = { b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6 };
    int count = 0;
    for (boolean item: array) {
        if (item) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count == 2;
}
```

This is pretty straightforward, no need to explain.

Answer (score 2):

How about changing the implementation so that it takes an array of booleans as parameters? This way you can insert any amount of boolean values using the same method and even change the amount of required true-values by adding an additional parameter.

```
boolean my_method(boolean ... values) {
    int nTrue = 0;
    for (boolean b : values) {
        if (b) {
            nTrue++;
        }
    }

    if (nTrue == 2)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kayaman's comment made think; I would have answered similarly to Sweeper, but if this is an interview question, and you can't use loops or arrays, how about a divide and conquer technique like this:

```
public boolean method(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c, boolean d, boolean e, boolean f) {
      if ((a || b || c) && (d || e || f)) {
       return true;
      } else if ((a || b || c)) {
       if (a && b) {
        return true;
       } else if (b && c) {
        return true;
       } else if (a && c) {
        return true;
       }
      } else if ((d || e || f)) {
       if (d && e) {
        return true;
       } else if (e && f) {
        return true;
       } else if (d && f) {
        return true;
       }
      } 
      return false;
 }
```